# Java- HashSet and CalendarDate

Tags: java, calendar, hashset

So I have to create a program that will do this:
rather than printing out a hashset like {1,91,71,5,45,7,9}, it must print out:

```
[0]   [1]   [2]   [3]   [4]   [5]   [6]   [7]   [8]   [9]
       1                       5           7           9
       91                      45
       71
```

Seems like the pattern is pretty simple
However, I have to do it for HashSet CalendarDate

the result of printing 1/1 through 1/8 is this

```
[0]   [1]   [2]   [3]   [4]   [5]   [6]   [7]   [8]   [9]
      1/6   1/2   1/8                           1/7
      1/3         1/5                           1/4
                  1/1
```

So what exactly is the pattern here? I can't seem to figure it out.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is a CalendarDate? What is the exact class you are putting in the HashSet? Example: java.util.Calendar

Comment: Or do you have to write your own HashSet implementation that can print out it's contents like in your examples?